# How to read from child's stdout while it still alive

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen, psutil

I created two scripts, when one of the scripts executes the other script and tries to receive it's output in real time.

The script that tries to get the output:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("python .\\print.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.stdout.readline()
```

The second script:

```
import time
print "1se12d12d32d3223"
print "\r"
time.sleep(10000)
```

The problem is that I get the output only when the child process dies, even though the line was already written to stdout.

I tried the following:

- Using os.pipe as an argument to Popen and then reading from the "read" pipe
- Using shell=True as Popen argument
- Using bufsize=1 as Popen argument
- Using stdout.read(), stdout.readlines(), stdout.read(1), etc...
- I can't use the fcntl module to make the pipe "Not blocking", because I use Windows

All I'm trying to do, is read the first line of stdout of the child process while the process is still alive. How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Python buffers its output. Output is automatically flushed under some circumstances. E.g. when you run the second script in a terminal, you will see the output immediately.

You can explicitly flush the output by inserting a `sys.stdout.flush()` before your `sleep()` call.